# Add users to an automated SharePoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow that starts when an item is created. If an amount is X, the X approval workflow starts. If the amount is XX, the XX approval workflow starts. If the amount is XXX I need the XXX workflow to route to the first approver who can then add additional approvers at his descretion.

The first 2 workflows are fine, how do I accomplish the third?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are your amounts. i.e. X. Don't use an out of the box approval workflow. Custom design a list workflow in SPD.

So something like this

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1tkm.png) to view an example of what I'm talking about

You could also take a look at the following link on how to go about setting this up

http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html